# linux servers configuration management best practice

Tags: linux, configuration-management

I have a bunch of servers where I periodically need to perform various operations, such as adding new repositories, installing packages, changing a couple of lines in configuration files, what approaches exist to propagate such changes? Which are the most convenient and simple?

Comment: You can use Ansible

Comment: Search the Internet for documentation/case studies/blogs/podcasts regarding tools to do a task. Pick your favorite and ask its support channels how to do more tasks. This is far too general and opinionated to be answered on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to adopt the "Configuration as code" paradigm. You can use Ansible, Chef, Puppet or Salt to name just a few. 
My personal preference is Ansible as it needs little configuration on the host and is easy to start working with.